# How to generalize a function written for a specific column in a dataframe to be usable on any similar column?

Tags: python, function, dataframe

How can I adjust this code so that it is useable for any column in the dataframe? Currently it only works on the column called "Gaps", but I have 10 other columns to which I need to apply this same function.

```
def get_averages(df: pd.DataFrame, column: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    '''
    Add a column in place, with the averages
    of each `Num` cyclical item for each row
    '''
    # work with a new dataframe
    df2 = (
        df[['FileName', 'Num', column]]
        .explode('Gaps', ignore_index=True)
    )
    
    df2.Gaps = df2.Gaps.astype(float)
    
    df2['tag'] = ( # add cyclic tags to each row, within each FileName
        df2.groupby('FileName')[column]
            .transform('cumcount') # similar to range(len(group))
        % df2.Num # get the modulo of the row number within the group
    )
    
    # get averages and collect into lists
    df2 = df2.groupby(['FileName', 'tag'])[column].mean() # get average
    df2.rename(f'{column}_avgs', inplace=True)
    
    # collect in a list by Filename and merge with original df
    df2 = df2.groupby('FileName').agg(list)
    df = df.merge(df2, on='FileName')
    
    return df

df = get_averages(df, 'Gaps')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter variable instead of hard-coding the column name:

```
    df2 = (
        df[['FileName', 'Num', column]]
        .explode(column, ignore_index=True)
    )
    df2[column] = df2[column].astype(float)
```